# How to add Class on multiple node dynamically cytoscape.js

Tags: vue.js, web, graph, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

**cytoscape.js**
New to cytoscape.
I have a select input.
**I want to add a class on multiple node on select input change.**

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) is very good. Read it.

Just call [addClass](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.addClass) function on the elements you want to add class